# How can I use Icalcs to grant access to a specific machine on the network?

Tags: batch, shared-folders, icacls

In a Batch File I want to use Icacls to grant access to either all users (preferable) or a specific user on a remote machine. Currently, if I grant access to the user Joe, any machine on the network can change it if their username is Joe.

Comment: Do you have an Active Directory domain, or is this a bunch of standalone (workgroup) PCs?

Comment: Im afraid I dont know what you mean. I've shared a folder on one computer, and others access it with `\\MyPCHostName\Folder\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any machine on the network can change it if their username is Joe.

No – if their username is Joe **and** their password matches Joe's password on your computer. The username is authenticated with a password.

However, nothing like that exists for the computer name – SMB connections made by users do not identify the machine, at least not in a secure manner. (Although NTLM includes the computer name, it is not secure – so any machine on the network could access your files by simply renaming the computer.)

(Exception: SMB connections made by system services running as NetworkService on a computer member of Active Directory will use the machine's AD credentials in place of the user credentials.)